# Connect to RabbitMQ server using Swift on Mac OS or IOS?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, rabbitmq

I have an application that works fine on windows and would like to make a port to use on IOS and Mac OS. The app uses RabbitMQ, but I have been unable to find much in the way of examples or documentation for how to get this done.

I have the server setup running on AWS, the example I'm looking for is just the client side of the RabbitMQ connection.

Does anyone know of any sample code that can do this using Swift? Expression C should work as well but Swift code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think anyone has ported a client *RabbitMQ* library over to *Swift* as of yet.

There's nothing listed on the official RabbitMQ site (http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) and searching for *librabbitmq swift* on *Github* comes up empty.

I think your best bet is probably to use the *Objective-C* wrapper of the *librabbitmq* library.

See the following page for more info, including usage examples:

https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc

Here's some info about importing *Objective-C* into *Swift*:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: What I thought. Thanks for the confirmation and the links!

Comment: @Kelly did you ever get your Swift Rabbit MQ wrapper working?  I am very interested in this (want to implement a Swift app to my existing RabbitMQ application).

Comment: No sorry, the project was put on hold due to something else more important and so I was never able to complete the work. But I would be very interested if you have a solution.